# Is it possible to programmatically parse an OkHttp response into a RetrofitError?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I don't see how to do it. To even call `RetrofitError.httpError()`, you need a `Retrofit.client.Response` instead of the `OkHttp` response, which is what we get.

Comment: why would you want to do that ? use Retrofit if you want the high level thing, okhttp for the low level thing. But why mixing boths ?

Comment: @mbonnin In the header interceptor, we want to log it. We could log it later, but just wanted to know if there was an easy way to log it there.

Comment: why don't you log the OkHttp error ? Do you specifically need a RetrofitError ?